# Pig: how to list Hive partitions and add new partitions to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, addition, partition

I have a Hive table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (
    column1 string,
    column2 string
) PARTITIONED BY (datestamp string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION '/path';
```

In Hive I can list partitions of this table with: `show partitions t1`
In Hive I can add partitions to this table with: `add partition...`

How can I do these 2 commands in Pig (Grunt)? (show Hive partitions and Add Hive partition)

I could not find these 2 commands (list partitions, add partitions) for Pig in `org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader()`

Is there any working example for Pig to do these 2 commands?

Answer (score 0):

In grunt you can run shell commands using sh .

So try this

```
grunt> sh hive -e "SHOW databases"
grunt> sh hive -e "USE database;ALTER TABLE table_name PARTITION partition_spec RENAME TO PARTITION partition_spec;"
```

Comment: This works but is launching new instance of Hive in order to do that.. I was hoping it can do much faster than launching new Hive every time.. Something like 'short circuit' access in order to show/add partitions..

Comment: there is no other way, you can do ls on table location to see partitions, but its not suggested, Sometimes partitions might not be added to metadata.

Comment: Is there a way to have Hive shell always open and launch external requests to Hive (from external scripts - e.g. from Pig or Shell scripts)? Currently it takes over 20sec to open new Hive session every time until it loads all libraries..

Comment: i dont think so, you dont have anyother option i guess.